# Дата регистрации домена - как определить?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Интересует вопрос, каким образом можно определить дату регистрации домена?

Наработки:

```
$url ='google.ru';
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.reg.ru/whois/?dname='.$url);
preg_match('/<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td style="width: 170px;">.*<td>(.*)<|Creation Date:(.*)\n|Domain Create Date:(.*) UTC/Uis', $content, $date));
...
```

Т.е. если зона домена .ru, то регистратор выдаёт одно содержание (к примеру, там возле даты регистрации написано "Дата регистрации:"), если же в .com, то другое (прим.: "Created on..............:"), если в .[com.ua](http://com.ua), то там тоже другое (прим.: "created:"). В общем получается, что всё время различаются зоны, а еще бывает и такое ( http://www.reg.ru/whois/?dname=yandex.com ) - т.е. хрен его знает когда зарегистрировали домен.

Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.phpwhois.org/
Если очень хочется изобретать свой велосипед - смотреть внутрь whois.parser.php, whois.main.php, и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Тот-же [reg.ru](http://reg.ru) ссылается на [safenames.net](http://safenames.net). по ссылке:
http://safenames.net/DomainNames/WhoisSearch.aspx
инфа:
domain:        [YANDEX.RU](http://YANDEX.RU)
....
created:       1997.09.23
Так что все зависит от выдачи сайта.
Почитай о протоколе WHOIS http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS
Кстати, тут более стандартизированная выдача:
http://www.ripn.net/nic/whois/index.html